# d3js dont drawing path

Tags: json, d3.js, path, jscript

Axises drawn well done, but path is invisible.And no error messages in the console. Please help understand where is the problem.

```
function Chart(id, data) {
        var chartData = JSON.parse(data);
        const height = 800;
        const width = 900;
        var svg = d3.select(id)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
        var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S");
        var lineLvl = d3.line()
            .x(function (d) {
                return Date.parse(parseDate(d.timeData));
            })
            .y(function (d)
            {
                return d.lvlData;
            });
        var xscale =
            d3.scaleTime()
                .domain([Date.parse(parseDate(chartData[0].timeData))-60000,
                    Date.parse(parseDate(chartData[chartData.length - 1].timeData)) + 60000])
                .range([0, width*0.95]);
        var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(chartData, function (d) { return d.lvlData*1.1; } )] )
            .range([height / 2, 0]);
        var x_axis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xscale)
            .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M"));
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("stroke", "blue")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("d", lineLvl(chartData));
        var y_axis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yscale);
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(50, 10)")
            .call(y_axis);
        var xAxisTranslate = height / 2 + 10;
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(50, " + xAxisTranslate + ")")
            .call(x_axis);
    }
```

Data represented by array of structures like this

```
{"timeData":"17.07.2020 14:38:10","lvlData":"146575","temperatureData":"24","volumeData":"6155"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the scales to your data when plotting it:

```
    var lineLvl = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) {
            return xscale(Date.parse(parseDate(d.timeData))); // run the x value through the x scale
        })
        .y(function (d)
        {
            return yscale(d.lvlData); // run the y value through the y scale
        });
```

The reason you see no error is because the line is drawn, but with unscaled values it is drawn a long ways off the SVG. If you inspect the SVG, you'll see the path, it's drawn, just that its coordinates reflect the raw data, not the scaled data.